# Blind signing when trying to send USDT over Arbitrum network

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, erc20, evm

i am trying to send USDT ERC20 token through arbitrum network and all things go well until i want to personally sign it using my hardware wallet. seems like the ABI is wrong or corrupt as i get bling signing transaction message.

has anyone come across this before or does any one know off the shelf solution for issues like this? The Dapp i am building is having issues when trying to send USDT from arbitrum network even when i am using ABI provided by arbiscan.

Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.

Thanks Heaps.

Tried sending USDT token through arbitrum network, can send it from browser extension wallet but when i try to send it from a hardware wallet, i get blind signing error

Answer (score 0):

Things you could do or check are maybe double check abi on Arbiscan just to make sure the abi ur using matches if that doesn’t work then checj for a firmware update on ur hardware wallet